# scipy.optimize.root returning incorrect solution

Tags: python, scipy, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of simultaneous equations as follows:

```
"145.0x/21025 = -0.334" 
"(-48.402x-96.650y+96.650z)/21025 = -0.334" 
"(-48.402x+132.070y+35.214z)/21025 = -0.334" 
"sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 145.0"
```

I am using the following Python script:

```
from scipy.optimize import root
from numpy import sqrt
from sys import argv, stdout

initGuesses = eval(argv[1])
equations = argv[2:]

def f(variables):
    x,y,z = variables
    results = []
    for eqn in equations:
        results.append(eval(eqn))
    return results

solution = root(f, initGuesses, method="lm")
stdout.write(str(solution["x"][0]) + "," + str(solution["x"][1]) + "," + str(solution["x"][2]))
stdout.flush()
```

The program is called as follows:

```
python3 SolvePosition3D.py "(1,1,1)" "(145.0*x+0.0*y+0.0*z)/21025.0+0.334" "(-48.402*x-96.650*y+96.650*z)/21025+0.334" "(-48.402*x+132.070*y+35.214*z)/21025+0.334" "sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)-145.0"
```

And I am receiving the following output:

```
48.2699997956,35.4758788666,132.042180583
```

This solution is wrong; the correct solution is roughly

```
-48,-35,-132
```

which is the same numbers but * -1.

The answer returned by the program satisfies the final equation, but violates all others.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Getting the correct solutions to these equations (and many others like them) is vitally important to my current project.

Comment: At the very least add your imports statements, as the code seems rather wonky without those.

Comment: In the code you're missing your imports, also problems with indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run the code via adding

```
from numpy import sqrt
from scipy.optimize import root
```

and switching to regular old prints for the solution.

Your starting guess seems to be wrong. Starting from (1, 1, 1), the root finder converges to `48.2699997956,35.4758788666,132.042180583`, as you said. If you plug in `(-1,-1,-1)`, you get `-48.2649482763,-35.4698607274,-132.050694891` as expected.

As for why it does that, well, nonlinear systems are just hard to solve like that. Most algorithms tend to find solutions deterministically based on the starting point. If you need to try multiple starting points, try a grid-based search.

Comment: So you're telling me that Scipy is perfectly fine converging to an incorrect root and then claiming it is correct? Great.

Comment: It's more that by using `"lm"` in `solution = root(f, initGuesses, method="lm")` you're deciding to use the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, which is a least squares one. SciPy will do what it can with this constraint and find the point of closest approach to zero, but the direction it first tries (depending on your starting guess) may not let it converge to zero exactly. Either try another algorithm or try some sort of heuristic for the starting guess.

Comment: Using lm is necessary as I must solve where number of equations > number of unknowns. By putting in more intelligent starting guesses, it now works for all examples I have tried so far. Hopefully it will continue to do so.